# How to create new user to existing directory

Tags: linux

I'm trying to add new user to existing directory. The goal is to create new vsftpd account on Debian.

Here is what I try:

```
useradd --base-dir path/to/dir new_username
```

it returns

```
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
```

What I miss ?

Comment: BTW, when you say "add user to existing directory", do you want the user's home dir to be `/path/to/dir` or `/path/to/dir/new_user`? `--base-dir` will do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of `useradd` only allows the use of `--basedir` (`-b`) with the `-D` flag.

If you cannot updated your version of `useradd`, try using that flag in conjunction with `-D`.

```
useradd -D -b /some/path # first update defaults
useradd new_user # then add user
```

#### Update:

Looking at the [source history for `useradd.c` (pkg-shadow)](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pkg-shadow/upstream/trunk/src/useradd.c?r1=1355&r2=1364) confirms that older versions of `useradd` would only allow `-b` with the `-D` option. That was [reported as a bug (on passwd)](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=480784) and has since been fixed.

Based on the tag history and revision numbers, my guess is that fix would be in pkg-shadow >= 4.1.0. What version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo useradd -b /home/myuser temp` works for me. Is your `path/to/dir` valid?

Comment: Yes, a valid...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you got a space somewhere in the base directory path. Also, it must be absolute (start with a slash). Try

```
useradd --basedir '/path/to/my dir' new_username
```

Comment: I double check that. Everything looks fine.